# Setting up RAID1 with an active physical volume (Debian 9 stretch)

Tags: lvm, raid, raid1

I've been trying to follow the following guide to set up RAID1:
https://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-raid1-on-a-running-lvm-system-debian-etch

I currently have two 6TB hard drives, I created a physical volume directly on one of them, the other is brand new and untouched.

```
sdc                8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk
├─DATA-user_data 254:0    0     4T  0 lvm
└─DATA-app_data  254:1    0     1T  0 lvm
sdd                8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk
```

The `sdc` physical volume has a single volume group on it containing two logical volumes

```
root@server:# pvscan
  PV /dev/sdc   VG DATA            lvm2 [5.46 TiB / 469.03 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [5.46 TiB] / in use: 1 [5.46 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
root@server:# vgscan
  Reading volume groups from cache.
  Found volume group "DATA" using metadata type lvm2
root@server:# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/DATA/user_data' [4.00 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/DATA/app_data' [1.00 TiB] inherit
```

I've come to the point in the guide where I need to copy the partition table from `sdc` to `sdd`, but of course this isn't possible as `sdc` doesn't have a partition table on it.

How can I setup RAID1 with `sdc` and `sdd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create mirror volumes by adding `sdd` to VG

```
pvcreate /dev/sdd
vgextend DATA /dev/sdd
```

and then change the number of copies of each LV

```
lvconvert -m1 DATA/user_data
lvconvert -m1 DATA/app_data
```

(1 mean two copies of data, 0 mean one copy)
You can check the progress of mirroring by command like:

```
lvs -a -o name,copy_percent,devices DATA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've taken this approach as it better suited my configuration.  Is there any way I can then test that this is working once the initial mirroring is complete?  So for example if I add a bunch of files, is there any way I can confirm/test these are being mirrored or does it write to both copies at the same time like RAID?

Comment: @JamqesBarndonius, using vgs, vgck, vgdisplay you can see different information about the VG. Same about the LVs. Check here of cheatsheet about LVM: http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/redhat/rh_lvm.htm

Comment: Thanks again :)  I also took a read of this which gave me a better understanding of how mirrored LVs work: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/mirrored_volumes

Answer (score 1):

Well, the *lazy* option would be to just take the current configuration in stride, add `/dev/sdd` to LVM as is, and let LVM itself handle the RAID for you. That means `mdadm` isn't involved at all (not directly, anyway). See Romeo's answer, it's a good one.

If you want to use `mdadm`, although it's not impossible to do this belatedly (using version 1.0 metadata at the end of disk), the *proper way* to do it would be to partition `/dev/sdd`, put `mdadm` RAID on the partition, put LVM on the RAID, and migrate data over. And once you've confirmed the copy is good, you could dissolve `/dev/sdc`, partition it the same way, and add it to the RAID.

Roughly:

```
# partition step
parted /dev/sdd
(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) mkpart md0_0 1MiB -1MiB
(parted) print free
(parted) quit

# mdadm step
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdd1 missing
mdadm --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf

# lvm step (rsync variant, two independent copies)
vgcreate RAIDDATA /dev/md0
lvcreate ...
mkfs ...
mount ...
# LV structure and filesystems as you see fit, then copy everything over
rsync -a /mnt/DATA/. /mnt/RAIDDATA/.

# alternative lvm step (pvmove variant, single copy)
vgextend DATA /dev/md0
pvmove /dev/sdc
vgreduce DATA /dev/sdc
```

Migrating the files over with `rsync` should be faster and safer (anything goes wrong, the original copy is still there). At the same time it's prone to user error (hard to tell if `rsync` missed something).

Migrating the data over with `pvmove` is slower and riskier (anything goes wrong, original copy is kind of gone, too) but it won't miss anything (including deleted files and such).

At this point you want to update UUIDs (if you used mkfs, rsync) in fstab / grub and update initramfs. Reboot and verify that everything is in order and that `/dev/sdc` is no longer in use. Then you can add it to the RAID.

```
# partition step
parted /dev/sdc
(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) mkpart md0_1 1MiB -1MiB
(parted) print free
(parted) quit

# raid resync step
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
watch -n 60 cat /proc/mdstat
```

And that's about it...

All in all it would give you the setup most people expect (hard drive, partitions, raid, lvm, filesystems). You could add encryption while you're at it, too. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response, while this would be the better answer for making use of RAID1 and mdadm, I decided to go for the mirrored logical volumes as it seemed to suit my configuration better.  I managed to achieve encryption by encrypting the file systems on the logical volumes, which gave me the added flexibility of being able to encrypt some things and not others (e.g. encrypt sensitive user data, don't bother with encrypting app data).